# ExpressionEngine no longer parsing tags

Tags: expressionengine

I'm in the middle of moving an EE 2.4 site to a new server. I pulled down the current site, moved it, and I noticed the tags in the page templates were no longer parsing. But, template parts (header, footer) parse correctly. I then set it up locally no my machine with MAMP to debug and found the same thing was happening there. Has anyone else ever run into this? I've seen some strange EE bugs before, but this one is new. You can see it at `http://192.241.176.212/`.

I have a hunch it's a permissions issue. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd definitely make sure your permissions are setup properly per the section here http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/installation.html#set-file-permissions have you double checked that?

Comment: Actually just fixed it. Turned out to be a PHP script that was trying to pull something in that wasn't there.

Comment: Happy to hear you got it sorted out!